# Vue3 - How do I access global property in composition setup API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm brand new to Vue.  The documentation says that the "setup" composition API is likely to be the one supported in the future so I'm trying to use that form everywhere.

I want to use a plugin, but I can't work out how to get access to it in the setup API format.

[Here is the supplied example](https://github.com/guruahn/vue3-google-oauth2-front-sample/blob/153d87538476f629a634213c0adf71577d01a69a/src/components/HelloWorld.vue#L54) of how to do it in Composition API:

```
const authCode = await this.$gAuth.getAuthCode();
```

When I try to use the plugin in setup form of composition API then I get an error `"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$gAuth') "`

The LOC that is producing that error looks like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
... stuff ...
const googleUser = await this.$gAuth.signIn();
```

My main.ts looks like this:

```
import gAuthPlugin  from "vue3-google-oauth2";

app.use(gAuthPlugin , {
  clientId: "768834812579-ivi0oopbkqe05cg6t41p83t7gteekut6.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  scope: "email",
  prompt: "consent",
  fetch_basic_profile: false,
});
```

I can see that the plugin is defining a global property ([here](https://github.com/guruahn/vue3-google-oauth2-front-sample/blob/153d87538476f629a634213c0adf71577d01a69a/src/plugins/vue3-google-oauth2.js#L131)), which the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties) says can be accessed on any component instance inside the application.

But the documentation only shows an example for composition (without setup) and I can't work out the syntax for this. It's quite similar to the problem raised in the comment to this [downvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68850731/821275) (the actual answer didn't help me there).

Comment: You cannot use `this` within setup, only within methods or computed properties. If you want to use `$gAuth` as a global property within setup, this discussion might help: `https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-globalproperties-in-vue-3-setup-method/108387/3`

Comment: Where in the docs do you see: `The documentation says that the "setup" composition API is likely to be the one supported in the future so I'm trying to use that form everywhere.`?

Comment: I think you're right - I can't find it in the official documentation.  In fact the official documentation says the opposite - that there are no plans to drop support for options API.

Comment: Indeed, it's a [common misconception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68611657/do-i-have-to-use-the-composition-api-in-vue-3-or-can-i-still-do-things-the-vue/68628205#68628205).